# How to play Storyboard in ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I defiend a storyborad in View

```
  <Storyboard x:Key="ExpandAdd" >
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="AddUsers" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="DetailBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0.4"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="DetailBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsEnabled)">
                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False"/>
            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
```

I have a button and bind to a relaycommand .

```
<Button x:Name="AddUserButton"  Content="اضافه">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding AddUsers}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

I want to play storyboard when RelayCommand(AddUsers) is execute.

Comment: You don't need to use Behaviors - `Button` controls support `Commands` natively, so you could just do: `<Button x:Name="AddUserButton" Command="{Binding AddUsers}"/>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not access `Storyboard` from your `ViewModel`. It defeats the purpose of `MVVM` altogether.

You can apply storyboard on `Button.LostMouseCapture` event which gets raised after your command gets called on `Click` event -

```
<Button x:Name="AddUserButton"  Content="اضافه">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding AddUsers}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <Button.Triggers>
       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.LostMouseCapture">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ExpandAdd}">
       </EventTrigger>
   </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this is relatively easy to do by using a DataTrigger that is bound to a property in the ViewModel, thus triggering the Storyboard from the MV while still maintaining separation of concerns. Here's a very brief example where a Storyboard grows an image in size in response to a bool in the VM changing to True.

```
<Image
    Grid.Row="0" 
    x:Name="LockImage"
    Source="/StoryboardManagerExample;component/Resources/LockedPadlock.png" 
    Width="50"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="ptScale" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
            <SkewTransform />
            <RotateTransform />
            <TranslateTransform />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Image.RenderTransform>

    <Image.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding RunStoryboard}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                From="50"
                                To="100"
                                Duration="0:0:1"
                                RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                AutoReverse="True"
                                />

                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could call the Storyboard from a code-behind as long as you assigned it x:Name. But then, you'd need to implement a button_click event handler, not a command for the ViewModel.

If you're using MVVM then you should really abide by the principle that the ViewModel should not "know" about specifics of the View.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't trigger the storyboard from the viewmodel. If you do then there is no point having a viewmodel.

Implement any code for the relay command in the code behind of the view, then if needed you can call through to the viewmodel to do anything 
that is viewmodel specific. When you reference the storyboard from the code behind of the view you can just refer to it by name.

Comment: Thanks, but i want paly it when `AddUsers` execute, Can i use a behavior for run a storyboard when `EventToCommand` execute?

Answer (score 0):

**For UWP**: You can define your storyboard in `VisualStates` and run it by changing property in ViewModel. If you change `IsRefreshWorking` property to `true` animation begins.

Define VisualState, using IsTrueTrigger:

```xml
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
       <VisualStateGroup x:Name="RefreshProgressVisualStates">
          <VisualState x:Name="NotWorkingVisualState" />
          <VisualState x:Name="WorkingVisualState">
             <Storyboard  AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="360" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="RefreshIcon" />
             </Storyboard>
             <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <StateTrigger  IsActive="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsRefreshWorking, Mode=OneWay}" />
             </VisualState.StateTriggers>
          </VisualState>
       </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

AppBarButton with animation:

```
<AppBarButton>
  <AppBarButton.Icon>
     <SymbolIcon x:Name="RefreshIcon"  Symbol="Refresh" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
         <SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
         </SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
      </SymbolIcon>
  </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```