# C# - WPF Access elements in a DataTemplate from code behind

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, storyboard, datatemplate

I tried to create a card game in WPF.
My Problem is that I want to flip a card at a certain time.
I created two storyboards in a datatemplate, one for each flip (back and front). But when I tried to access and start it from the code behind I got an error, because it can't access the grid, which contains the new card image, inside the datatemplate.
So my question is, how can I access the grid inside the datatemplate from code behind, to get my storyboard run?

Here is my code:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="KartenQuartett.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KartenQuartett"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Title="{Binding Title}" Height="510" Width="670" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RotatingItemTemplate">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-1">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid1">
                    <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                    <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
                    <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                    <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                    <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                    <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
                </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1_reversed">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-1"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid1">
                    <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                    <SplineInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
                    <SplineInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
                </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                    <SplineInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
                    <SplineInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                    <SplineInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
                </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Grid x:Name="grid">
                <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                        <SkewTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                        <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <Grid x:Name="grid1">
                <Image x:Name="image1" Source="{Binding ImageFront}" Stretch="Fill" />
                                            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                           </Grid>
                <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Fill" />
            <Button x:Name="Bdrehen" Content="Drehen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="119,407,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Bdrehen_Click"/>
            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger  RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="Bdrehen">
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard1_BeginStoryboard1" Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown" SourceName="grid1">
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard1_BeginStoryboard1"/>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard1_reversed_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1_reversed}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="gridOne">
        <Image x:Name="cardFront" Source="Bilder/card_front.png" Stretch="Fill">
        </Image>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stack1" Margin="25">

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="gridTwo">

            <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyImages}" 
                          ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" 
                          ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource RotatingItemTemplate}">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>

                <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">

                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>

                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>

        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>

        <StackPanel x:Name="stack2" Margin="25">
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

So "grid" and "grid1" are the elements, which can't accessed.

For tests i created a button "Bdrehen" to check, if I can access the flip from a button. This works perfect, it also works by left-clicking on it with the mouse. But not by code.

Heres the code, where I try to start it from code behind:

```
DataTemplate dt = (DataTemplate)FindResource("RotatingItemTemplate");            
    Storyboard sb = dt.Resources["Storyboard1_reversed"] as Storyboard;
    BeginStoryboard(sb);
```

After starting I got an error, that the "grid" can't be found in the namespace of "KartenQuartett.MainWindow".
I can find my storyboards, but not my grids inside the datatemplate.

Anyone got an idea to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer [Calling Storyboard inside DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522427/calling-storyboard-inside-datatemplate).

But keep in mind that doing that is not a good idea. Accessing any UI Element from your code behind is not a great idea, because it creates a tight coupling between your code and your UI.

I would suggest you to use [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) instead, and to bind a boolean to run your storyboard as explained here: [How to play Storyboard in ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769849/how-to-play-storyboard-in-viewmodel)

Comment: Thanks. But I still got the Problem, that I can't access anything inside the datatemplate. After changing the "DataTemplate.Resources" to "Grid.Resources" like in the example, I can't access my storyboard. I can only access my datatemplate, but nothing inside.

Comment: After trying a while I made it. I created a "Loaded"-Event for the grid to access the storyboards indside. Thanks a lot for your help.