# binding Storyboard in Usercontrol to Storyboard object in Viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

before asking this question, I have searched through for it, but my case is different.
I have a named Storyboard in UserControl like that:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1" >
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="180"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="360"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="smartphone_png">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.6" Value="205.5"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.2" Value="205.5"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="466.667"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="466.667"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="632.334"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:7" Value="706.001"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="smartphone_png">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:7" Value="53.333"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8" Value="196.166"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

and in ViewModel for this Usercontrol, I have something like this for binding to Storyboard1 Storyboard:

```
Storyboard BoardControl = new Storyboard();

var resource =?? \\this line is what I need to bind to Storyboard1

BoardControl = resource as Storyboard;
BoardControl.Stop();
```

I Have tried:

> object resource = Application.Current.TryFindResource("Storyboard1");

it was wrong because seems like it initializes a new Storyboard1 object, It was not the same object as the beginning.

Any idea for me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to create or use a Storyboard in your view model? Storyboards belong to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You don't control nor access a `Storyboard` from a view model class.

If you need to programmatically control the `Storyboard`, you should do this from the code-behind of the view. You can then access the `Storyboard` resource like this:

```
Storyboard sb = this.Resources["Storyboard1"] as Storyboard;
```

Comment: Did you read my answer? You should *not* do this in the view model.

Comment: You could put the Storyboard in App.xaml and access it using Application.Current.Resources["Storyboard1"] but this is not MVVM.

Comment: for your question, I want to use it to control the flow of Storyboard, it means I am able to stop, pause,...the Storyboard. not only run it by click event from begin to the end.

Comment: You can set properties in the view model but you should never access the Storyboard itself: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531570/starting-an-animation-from-the-viewmodel-in-wpf-mvvm
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769849/how-to-play-storyboard-in-viewmodel